# Complex Jetpack navigation with bottom navigation and other child navigation strategies

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

What's the best way to implement navigation using single activity architecture and Jetpack navigation for an application with complex navigation that involves some different navigation strategies. For example:

- Main application navigation using bottom navigation
- In some of the bottom tabs fragments you can access some detail action that has its own navigation. For example, a detail view implemented:

  - as a full-screen fragment
  - without the bottom bar
  - with a top header with two tabs.

What's the best way to combine the main navigation with the two tabs from the detail view, or in general, more nested strategies.  It's better to use several navigation files or can be implemented using only one?

Comment: Child fragments aren't managed by Jetpack Navigation per say, the top-header with two tabs is most likely a regular ViewPager(2) as you always would.

Comment: Thanks, @EpicPandaForce, and in case that child has more complex navigation, for example, imagine the creation of a new item that involve several screens. Just try to have no nested child fragments and hide the bottom bar?

Comment: If you have a top tab on top of having a bottom nav, I sincerely doubt you'll be able to create something without nested child fragments, and actually have a reliable navigation mechanism. You'll basically be reimplementing the childFragmentManager, which already correctly handles state restoration across process death.